# How do I display the same navigation bar throughout many views?

Tags: ios

I can reproduce the following navigation bar for one view:

[image]

However, once I move to the next view after clicking a button, I lose the top two rightmost icons(Search, Profile).  I understand that setting up navigation item from a storyboard is usually per view.  I can replicate those items for each view but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it once.

Is there a tutorial that explains how to maintain a custom navigation bar across many views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set it up for every view. You should probably create a superclass and implement it there, so you only need to actually write the code once.