# Best way to share nav bar across multiple views?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have three view controllers that I want to have the same navigation bar on but I can't figure out a way to "share" the navbar between those three views.  Is there a more efficient way to link up the nav controllers with the view controllers so that I don't have three different navigation controllers even though the navigation controllers are exactly the same?

In addition, I have a tab bar controller if that makes a difference.

Picture to clarify:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display the same navigation bar throughout many views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741731/how-do-i-display-the-same-navigation-bar-throughout-many-views)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ch0k0I8 mentioned, `UIAppearance` is a good way to set a common UI theme throughout the app.

If you are looking for the same functionality between navigation controllers, then you should subclass `UINavigationController` and implement the common functionality there. Then you can use your custom navigation controller in the storyboard or in code in the 3 places you wish. To put your custom subclass in the storyboard, drag a `UINavigationController` onto the storyboard like you normally would, then change the class to your custom navigation controller class in the utilities tab. Here is what a custom `UINavigationController` subclass might look like:

```
class CustomNavController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // do whatever custom setup stuff you want here
    }

    // override other methods for different customizations
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my noobishness (I'm an Android programmer by heart), but what do you mean by "subclass[ing]" the UINavController?  I am also confused as to how I can make a custom navigation bar controller in the storyboard

Comment: Updated my answer. If you are an Android programmer, then you should be familiar with subclassing. Making Android and iOS apps are very similar, and much of it is based on object-oriented programming.

Comment: So I still basically need to add a separate nav controller for each view?

Comment: In the storyboard, yes you will need separate nav controllers. But that's just a click and drag. No big deal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use UIAppearance.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: color];
```

Comment: You can have a consistent UI in your app using UIApearance protocol. If it's not your case then it's wrong.

Comment: I'm looking to maintain the same functionality (i.e. buttons in the navbar) in addition to the color; can I do that with UIAppearance?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a storyboard, and from what you're describing, you don't need three nav controllers. Instead, connect the three `UIViewControllers` by ctrl-dragging from one to the next to create a push segue. Don't use the `UIAppearance` proxy; just set customize the bar's appearance in your navigation controller's `rootViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Do I still need to have three separate navigation controllers though?

Comment: @JacobPlatin Definitely not. I edited my answer. A nav controller controls, or contains, a flow through the app, such that each scene it contains segues into the next scene.